# When is it OK to cancel differentials?

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

I have seen quite a lot of questions to this effect on the StackExchange already, and have always justified the cancelling of differentials to myself in a rather hand-wavy sort of way - that is, until I was trying to work out some general way to solve an equation of the form:

$$ (f \circ a) (x) - (f \circ b) (x) = c(x) $$

Where I chose a simple $f(u)$, $a(x)$, $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ (like $ f(u) = u^2 $, $ a(x) = x $, $ b(x) = x^2 $ and then $ c(x) = x^2 - x^4 $ ), so as to see whether I could reverse engineer it somehow. My idea was roughly to try and exploit the chain rule by differentiating both sides and to see whether or not it would allow me to factor out some $\frac{df}{dx}$, but when applying the chain rule in the naive, hand-wavy way I mentioned above the cancelling of differentials would collapse the entire equation down to zero. To be more precise, after taking the derivative of

$$ f(x) - f(x^2) = x^2 - x^4 $$

I should have

$$ \frac{df}{da} * 1 - \frac{df}{db} * 2x = 2x - 4x^3 $$

But if I do it purely in terms of $f$, $a$, $b$, and $c$ with the chain rule, I get

$$ \frac{df}{da} * \frac{da}{dx} - \frac{df}{db} * \frac{db}{dx} = \frac{dc}{dx} $$

Which, after cancelling da/da and db/db, the equation is basically

$$ \frac{df}{dx} - \frac{df}{dx} = \frac{dc}{dx} $$ which must be equal to zero ...no?

Long story short, my question is: Have I done something really wrong? If not, what are the subtleties when cancelling differentials? Because right now I'm having a bit of a panic attack thinking that, in general, $\frac{df}{dx} \neq \frac{df}{dx}$ because of the intermediary differentials that may possibly have been cancelled. An answer in layman's terms would be preferred and I apologise in advance for not being able to format the equations properly, as I'm not all that familiar with actively engaging with this forum. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please take a look at the following link for some basic tips on formatting your post so it is easier to read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: and as a brief comment (but not worthy of an answer), differentials can usually be "canceled" when there is only a single variable at each stage of composition because of the single variable chain rule, i.e.  given $f(x)$ and $a(x)$ we have $\frac{df}{da} = \frac{df}{da} \frac{da}{dx}$. When you start mixing in multiple variables at a level of composition you have to start thinking about multivariable chain rule, which muddies the water a bit. Some tricks still work, and the language of differential forms is a nice way to deal with this, but you have to be a tad more careful.

Comment: There's also something to be said about the notation $\frac{df}{da}$ being a tad vague, since really it should read something like $\frac{d f(u)}{du} \big |_{u = a(x)}$. You are in some sense differentiating along a submanifold given by the image of the map $x \mapsto a(x)$, and so if we are also considering a separate submanifold given by $b(x)$ we might expect to have to be careful about our domains

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was not formatted in LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the symbol
$$\dfrac{df}{dx}$$
in three different ways and that is what is confusing you.
We can write $f$ as a shorthand for $f(x)$ and then
$$\dfrac{df}{dx}=\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}=f'(x)$$
Or we can write $f$ as a shorthand for $f(a(x))$ and then
$$\dfrac{df}{dx}=\dfrac{df(a(x))}{dx}=f'(a(x))a'(x) $$
Or we can write $f$ as a shorthand for $f(b(x))$ and then
$$\dfrac{df}{dx}=\dfrac{df(b(x))}{dx}=f'(b(x))b'(x) $$
If there is any scope for confusion it is best not to write $f$ as it can be ambiguous.
Now we can write
$$f(a(x)) - f(b(x)) = c(x)$$
and differentiate to get
$$f'(a(x))a'(x) - f'(b(x))b(x) = c'(x)$$
and now substitute  $f(u) = u^2, a(x) = x, b(x) = x^2 ,c(x) = x^2 - x^4 $
$$2x - 2x^2 2x = 2x-4x^3$$
or, if you prefer,
$$\dfrac{df(a(x))}{dx}-\dfrac{df(b(x))}{dx}=\dfrac{dc(x)}{dx}$$
$$\dfrac{df(a(x))}{da(x)}\frac{da(x)}{dx}-\dfrac{df(b(x))}{db(x)}\frac{db(x)}{dx}=\dfrac{dc(x)}{dx}$$
$$2a(x)1-2b(x) 2x=2x-4x^3$$
$$2x-4x^3=2x-4x^3$$

Comment: Thanks for your response, it is much appreciated! I take it that my main problem was that I was not specifying what "inside" function, i.e. $a(x)$ or $b(x)$, I had substituted for u in $f(u)$. I still, however, am a little confused as to why exactly this should fail in light of the standard chain rule, as $$\frac{d}{dx} f(u(x)) = \frac{df}{du} \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{df}{dx}$$ and shouldn't this then also apply to an $a(x)$ or $b(x)$ instead of a $u(x)$ ? Does it at the end of the day come down to the multivariable chain rule "muddying the waters" as  @Brevan Ellefsen had said above? If so, why?

Comment: You've made the same mistake again. $f(u(x))$, $f(a(x))$, $f(b(x))$ and $f(x)$ are all different things. When you write $\frac{df}{dx}$ it is not clear what the $f$ you are talking about.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. Thanks for clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to cancel differentials but you have to be careful with the notation. In your case $df$ is not the same. It's $df(a(x))$ and $df(b(x))$ so $\frac{df(a(x))}{dx}-\frac{df(b(x))}{dx} \ne 0$.